# Python Discord, connect as an user

Tags: python, discord, bots

So i try to make a selfbot (on my own server) who connect with a real account

```
import discord
import asyncio


client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.servers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email = input("Enter email: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    client.login(email, password)
```

And i've an error : `TypeError: login() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation of the `login` method?

Comment: Yes but only give "token" as argument without mentionning email or password

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.login

Answer (score 1):

First, You Can't call login method using email and password.

The only way is obtaining token.

**How to get token?**

```
Open Chrome Devtools: F12 on Web client or Ctrl+Shift+I on Electron client.

Select Network Tab and Record Network Activity.(Red Circle)

Click any other server, Select `Science` and Go end of Headers
Request Payload Tab - You will find your token.

Make token python variable and DO NOT SHARE CODE OR TOKEN!
```

**Caution**

But Beware and Better Not: **Selfbot Will Cause Ban you from discord!**

Comment: Are you sure ? I succeeded to get my token but when i do client.run(token) iv'e an error like [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1091)')]

Comment: And i do on my own server and i know the risks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Now i have my token i've an error
`discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

And i'm pretty sure that my token is correct